# VARCHAR TO DATE

Tags: sql-server

Currently i have a column called date as varchar instead of date time. the format is currently 'sep12'. How can i transfer this to a date type?
I know this is the template but I'm not sure what to change the numbers to due to my current format as MMMYY.

```
CAST (
    SUBSTRING(date, 3, 2) + '/' +
    SUBSTRING(date, 1, 2) + '/' +
    SUBSTRING(date, 5, 4) 
AS DATETIME)
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

At the moment when  ordering by the date field it is ordering like apr09, apr10. aug09, aug10 but I need it to be in year order

Comment: You should use a **language-independent** format - the ISO-8601 format is the best: `YYYYMMDD` (no dashes or slashes or anything!) - this works reliably with any language and/or dateformat setting in your SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, storing dates in this manner is a terrible idea. But if you know that the year will always start with `20` then you can use something like this (see [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/4619)):

```
declare @dt varchar(10) = 'Sep12'

select convert(datetime, left(@dt, 3) + '01 20' + right(@dt, 2), 100)
```

If pulling data from your table:

```
select convert(datetime, left(yourDateField, 3) + '01 20' + right(yourDateField, 2), 100)
from yourTable
```

Comment: Will I need to do this for every instance I have. Eg jan10 feb10 etc

Comment: @user1296762 see my edit, if you want to extract data from your table just replace the `@dt` variable with your date field.